# Minimal dynamical system with quasiperiodic oscillations

Tags: oscillators, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, quasi-periodic

What is a minimal, explicit dynamical system (as in, a series of coupled ordinary differential equations) that exhibits quasiperiodic oscillations for some region of parameter space? Two coupled Van der Pol oscillators have this property, for example; however I am hoping to find a dynamical system with a simpler form.

I am imagining something like a system of three variables, in which trajectories trace a spiral on a torus in three dimensional space.

Comment: Must it be a continuous system or a mapping (discrete time) is also fine?

Comment: I was hoping for ODEs, since the standard map is a pretty simple discrete time map with quasiperiodicity. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, that's where I was getting to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimum, if boring example is that of two uncoupled 1D linear ODE (with incommensurate constants) on a torus, such as can be found in [Hasselblatt & Katok](https://books.google.de/books?id=TcfLCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA113&ots=Tu3B8mxoQY&dq=uniform%20motion%20torus%20Katok%20Hasselblatt&pg=PA112#v=snippet&q=uniform%20torus&f=false):

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= \omega_1\\
\dot y &= \omega_2,
\end{aligned}
\right. \tag{4.2.3}
$$

whose trivial solution is

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x &= x_0 + \omega_1t\\
y &= y_0 + \omega_2t.
\end{aligned}
\right. \tag{4.2.4}
$$

The simplest nontrivial example I could find is the **forced van der Pol oscillator** (still simpler than the example of two of them coupled, mentioned in the OP), found, e.g., in [Guckenheimer's 1980 paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1084738) ([e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/John_Guckenheimer/publication/3185420_Dynamics_of_the_Van_der_Pol_equation/links/56debefa08aed4e2a99db846/Dynamics-of-the-Van-der-Pol-equation.pdf)):

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= y - \epsilon(x^3/3 -x)\\
\dot y &= -x+b\cos(\omega t),
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

which can be written as an autonomous system in 3D:

$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\dot x &= y - \epsilon(x^3/3 -x)\\
\dot y &= -x + b\cos z\\
\dot z &= \omega.
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

A numerically integrated quasiperiodic trajectory of this system, in normalized variables, can be found in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2016.12.013) ([e-print](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313406413_Continuation_of_quasi-periodic_solutions_with_two-frequency_Harmonic_Balance_Method)):

[image: Forced Van der Pol, time integration (ODE suite from Matlab).]